# Can I mute for youtube-ios-player-helper?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I'm using youtube-ios-player-helper to play youtube video in my application. I'd like to be able to mute. Here is what I did:

1. Add setVolume() and mute() function in YTPlayerView

   ```
   -(void)setVolume:(int)volume {

       if ( volume < 0 )
           volume = 0;
       else if ( volume > 100 )
           volume = 100;
       NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player.setVolume(%d);", volume];
       [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:command];
   }

   -(void)mute {        
       NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"player.mute();"];
       [self stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript:command];
   }
   ```

Then I call **setVolume:0** or **mute** functions in my app. But the sound can't be turned off. The volume is still 100.

Did anybody turn off the sound successfully?

Comment: See this issue on the project's GitHub page: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/20

Comment: Have you find any proper solution for it ?

Comment: Me too, have you find the workaround?

Comment: I used the exact same mute function you are using, but it only worked for me if I called that method right after I started playing the video, and the had to be ready when I called play. Edit: I called the `stringFromEvaluatingJavaScript` function on the `webView` property.

Answer (score 4):

Following the above I got it working in Swift4:

```
func playerView(_ playerView: YTPlayerView, didChangeTo state: YTPlayerState) {
    if case .playing = state {
        playerView.webView?.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "player.mute();")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To mute a video played using the youtube-ios-player-helper library in an iOS app, you can use either the `mute` method of the YTPlayerView class or add the mute parameter to the `playerVars` dictionary when initializing the YTPlayerView instance.

1. Using the mute method:

```
// Assuming you have created a YTPlayerView instance called playerView
playerView.muteSound = true // This will mute the audio of the video
```

You can set the `mute` property to true to mute the audio and false to unmute it. This can be useful if you want to give your users the ability to mute/unmute the video or if you want to mute the audio by default when the video starts playing.

2. Using the mute parameter in playerVars:

```
let playerVars: [String: Any] = [
    "controls": 0,
    "playsinline": 1,
    "autohide": 1,
    "showinfo": 0,
    "modestbranding": 1,
    "mute": 1 // for mute set 1 else 0
]

// Assuming you have created a YTPlayerView instance called playerView
playerView.load(withVideoId: "VIDEO_ID", playerVars: playerVars)
```

In this example, the `mute` parameter is set to `1`, which means the audio will be muted by default when the video starts playing. You can set the value of `mute` to `0` to unmute the audio by default.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can mute video of youtube I have added that feature to YTPlayerView 
https://github.com/abhay-singh/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/youtube-ios-player-helper/YTPlayerView%2BMute_unMute.h

you can clone or download that files from this link https://github.com/abhay-singh/youtube-ios-player-helper.git